# Show $\bigcup\limits_{n\mid n\geq N}A_{n,m}=\left\{\sup\limits_{n\mid n\geq N}\left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|\geq\frac{1}{m}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

> Let be $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p\in(0,1)$, $S_n$ is a binomially distributed random variable and
> $
> \begin{align*}
> &A_{n,m}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid \left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|\geq \frac{1}{m}\right\}.
> \end{align*}
> $
>
> Here, $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and we can assume that there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that $A_{n,m}\in \mathcal{F}$.
>
> Show that
> $
> \begin{align*}
> \bigcup\limits_{n\mid n\geq N}A_{n,m}=\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\sup\limits_{n\mid n\geq N}\left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|\geq\frac{1}{m} \right\}.
> \end{align*}
> $

---

The relation $\subset$ is not a problem but I am not sure why $\supset$ holds.

I tried to prove it with a contraposition $(\lnot B\implies \lnot A)\iff (A\implies B)$ but it gets me nowhere:

We choose an $\omega\in\Omega$ with $\sup\limits_{n\mid n\geq N}\left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|\geq\frac{1}{m}$ and fix it. If we assume that there exists **no** $n\geq N$ such that $\left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|\geq \frac{1}{m}$, then there must be a $n\geq N$ with $\left|\frac{S_n(\omega)}{n}-p\right|< \frac{1}{m}$. But this doesn't lead to a contradiction...

Any suggestions? Am I missing someting?

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but is $S_n$ a binomially distributed random variable with parameter $p$, or could it just be any parameter? Also does $S_n(\omega)$ mean the probability of getting the result $\omega$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla, yes $p$ can be understood as the probability of a success. $S_n(\omega)$ simply denotes the number of successes if we consider a Bernoulli trial of length $n$. But I don't think that this matters a lot.

Comment: I think I'm confused on what exactly $\Omega$ is (or maybe about how you're defining $S_n(\omega)$). If we suppose $p=1/2$ and $m=2$, then I think $|S_n(\omega)/n-p|\to 1/2$ if $\omega$ is the number of successes (no matter what specific value it is). But given $N$ sufficiently large, there doesn't exist an $n\ge N$ such that $|S_n(\omega)/n-p|\ge 1/2$, which implies that the $\supseteq$ direction is false.

Comment: If we write $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ where each $X_k$ is a Bernoulli($p$) random variable, can we assume that the sequence $\{X_k\}$ is independent? Because then here would be my thoughts: if $\sup_{n\geq N} |S_n/n - p| = m^{-1}$, then there exists $n\geq N$ with $|S_n(\omega)/n-p| = m^{-1}$, otherwise we get a violation of SLLN. However, even in this case we cannot fully claim the equivalence in the problem... we can only claim is differs by an event with probability 0.

Comment: @VarunVejalla, unfortunately we are only told that $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and that there exists an appropriate probability space. This means that the defined sets $A_{n,m}$ are elements of the $\sigma$-algebra. I have edited the question to incorporate your issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a strict inequality in the definition of $A_{n,m}$?

Comment: @Michh, this is how the problem was stated. Why should it be a strict inequality?